# Javascript Lightbox 2 Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox, conflict

I'm quite new at this, so please be thorough with the explanation. 
I'm using the Lightbox 2 jQuery file, along with another jQuery file to execute a menu slide animation and a fade animation on my images. 
I'm assuming that there is conflict between the two jQuery files, but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Any advice? I read something about jQuery.noConflict(), but I'm not sure how to implement it, or it if will work.

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div#ScrollBox img').animate({
        opacity:.5
    });
    $('div#ScrollBox img').hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity:1}, 'fast');
    }, function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity:.5}, 'slow');
    });
});

</script>

<!--LIGHTBOX-->
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Could you describe the results you are getting, and give the name of the other plugin you are using?

Comment: Hi Dan. 
Added the code. My lightbox opens up the images in a new window instead of a pop up window with a dimmed background.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are loading two different jQuery versions (1.10.2 and 2.0.2), which is, I believe, causing the problem. I would recommend removing the 1.10.2 jQuery script, and one of the following (in order of effort, in case you want to try all 3):
-see if your lightbox plugin still works
-find a newer version of the same lightbox
-use a different lightbox, for example [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)

In any case, make sure that your end result only has one version of jQuery being loaded.

Comment: Would  be able to replace <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> with <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">, or should I just take out the script source from the lightbox altogether?

Comment: Take out the extra jQuery script from the lightbox plugin completely, to see if it behaves with the version you are already using.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need both? They should have pretty much the same code so you only need to include one. I would use whichever is the latest.

It would help if you included in your post the lines of code where you explicitly add them so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: The cannot be a reason to include jQuery twice, and besides, it's a pretty big file to force a user to download twice!  Never include two instances of jQuery!